# AppCompatActivity not present in Backstack after hitting Home button

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an App that only uses Fragments with a single AppCompatActivity that works great.
When I start a new Activity from the AppCompatActivity, ie 3rd party barcode scanning, it also goes great. back, forward,etc.

navigation path like A -> B -> NewActivityX -> B -> A....

Until I hit the Home button on the new Activity!
It looks like the backstack is totally gone, I can navigate back to the new Activity but it won't go back to the AppCompatActivity but just closes the app...

navigation path like A -> B -> NewActivityX -> HOME -> NewActivityX -> Close..... ????

Any ideas?

FYI: I use MVVMCross, I think the problem isn't at MVVMCross because the AppCompatActivity doesn't even get a trigger by Android like AppCompatActivity.Resume or the Constructor of AppCompatActivity.

Comment: How do you manage your backstack? Did you know we also have an example available for using fragments in MvvmCross: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: @martijn00 Thanks, but it looks like a simplyfied version of what I made, also with the AppCompatActivity (or am I wrong). I will check if this solution has the same issue later, when I'm not in a train.

Comment: That example uses MvxCachingFragmentActivityCompat, which uses AppCompatActivity again. I made some fixes for backstack in this PR: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/pull/51/files